# Future.timeout(Duration()) weird behavior in Flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to make Interactor with lifetime and with no care for result, so i create an abstract class :

```dart
abstract class Interactor<P> {
  Stream<callStatus> call(P params,
      {Duration timeoutMs = defaultTimeoutMs}) async* {
    try {
      yield callStarted();
      await doWork(params).timeout(timeoutMs, onTimeout: () => throw TimeoutException(""));
      yield callSuccess();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      yield callError(e);
    }
  }

  @protected
  Future<void> doWork(P params);

  static const Duration defaultTimeoutMs = Duration(minutes: 5);
}
```

and each sub class can extend that and override the doWork() function :

```dart
class TestTimeOutInteractor extends Interactor<int> {
  @override
  Future doWork(int params, {timeoutMs: const Duration(seconds: 2)}) {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 6));
  }
}
```

but there is no exception thrown the test wait for 6 second and return success.
the test :

```dart
test('fails timeout exception', () async {
      await expectLater(TestTimeOutInteractor()(1),
          emitsInOrder([callStarted(), callError(TimeoutException(""))]));
    });
```

output of test is

```
ERROR: Expected: should do the following in order:
          • emit an event that callStarted:<callStarted>
          • emit an event that callError:<callError>
  Actual: <Instance of '_ControllerStream<callStatus>'>
   Which: emitted • callStarted
                  • callSuccess
                  x Stream closed.
            which didn't emit an event that callError:<callError>
```

Comment: `defaultTimeoutMs` is set to 5 *minutes*.  `doWork` completes in 6 *seconds* and never has a chance to timeout.  Incidentally, naming durations with `Ms` makes sense if the duration is stored as a number since you otherwise wouldn't know what units it represents, but it makes no sense for `Duration` objects which handle units for you.